# How to access two collections in mongodb MERN stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I have the:

- **Users** collection which contains user information such
  as the id, email, etc.
- **Movies** collection which contains the movie information such as the title, length, etc.
- **Wishlist** collection which contains the user email, and the movie id

I have the *user_email* stored in my server.js and would like to return all the movies in my **Wishlist** collection that has the same email as *user_email*.

My current code right now doesn't seem to work and looks like this:

```
app.get('/user/wishlist', (req, res) => { 
var arr_id = [];
var arr_movies = [];
Wishlist.find({user: user_email}, (err, data) => { 
    if (err) { 
        res.status(500).send(err)
    } else { 
        // this is different from 201 below
        console.log("view wishlist")
        console.log(data);
        data.map(id => { 
            arr_id.push(id["movie"]);
        })

        arr_id.map(movie => { 
            Movies.findOne({movie}, (err, movie) => {
                if (err) { 
                    res.status(500).send(err);
                } else { 
                    arr_movies.push(movie);
                }
            })
        })
        res.status(201).send(arr_movies);
    }
})
})
```

Data Structure for Movie:

```
const movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
image: String, 
title: String, 
rating: String, 
length: String, 
// timeslots: Array
timeslots: [{
    id: Number, 
    time: String, 
    seats: []
}]});
```

Sample Data:

```
 _id: 61d65a3431a314f4fc7e9170
   image:"https://static.onecms.io/wpcontent/uploads/sites/20
        /2021/08/25/spence..."
   title:"Spencer"
   rating:"R"
   length:"1 hr 57 min"
   timeslots:Array
     0:Object
     1:Object
     2:Object
   __v:0
```

Sample Data Structure for User:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
 firstName: String, 
 lastName: String, 
 email: String, 
 password: String, 
 confirmPassword: String, 
 kind: Number
})
```

Sample Data:

```
_id:618c993e75064eee04daead6
firstName: "Andrew"
lastName: "Yang"
email: "hello@gmail.com"
password: "test"
confirmPassword:"test"
kind:1
__v:0
```

Sample Data Structure for wishlist:

```
const wishlistSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    user: String, 
    movie: String
})
```

Sample Data:

```
_id:61e650edd75f3c74142222f0
user:"hello@gmail.com"
movie:"61d65a3431a314f4fc7e9170"
__v:0
```

Comment: Can you provide the data structures in each collection? Some sample data would be a huge help here. But the way you will accomplish this is via aggregation pipeline, specifically the lookup operator.

Comment: Hey I edited my question to show how the data looks like in my database. Thanks so much!!

Comment: You can use the `$lookup` aggregation stage to query data from two collections with related data.

Comment: please don't post screenshots. @CoderNewbie ... please post the raw data so it is easier to copy/paste and to help you. Help us help you.

Comment: my apologies! Edited my post. Hope that helps! :)